# error modulenotfounderror no module named 'mysqldb' airflow

Tags: airflow

line 5:-
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.mysql_to_gcs import mysqltogcsoperator

getting error as broken DAGS.

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/airflow.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/opt/airflow/dags/airflow.py", line 5, in 
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.mysql_to_gcs import MySQLToGCSOperator
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 25, in 
from MySQLdb.constants import FIELD_TYPE
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

no idea how to resolve